# undefined method `created_at' for ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've defined an ActiveRecord object that somehow doesn't have methods `created_at` or `updated_at`.

In the console:

```
a = Alert.find(1)
=> #<Alert id: 1, unread: false, alertable_type: "Comment", alertable_id: 1, membership_id: 1, stake_id: 1>
a.class
=> Alert(id: integer, unread: boolean, alertable_type: string, alertable_id: integer, membership_id: integer, stake_id: integer)
a.is_a? ActiveRecord::Base
=> true
a.created_at
NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for #<Alert:0x00000108b83b80>
```

There's nothing strange as far as I can tell in my schema or `alert.rb` though I'd be glad to post them. I've restarted my console. I've checked my last few dozen commits to make sure I didn't accidentally touch some config file somewhere.

I'm doing other ActiveRecord methods on Alert objects, for example `update_attributes`. Also `created_at` and `updated_at` are working normally for my other models. Any idea where I'd look next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

active record read attributtes form your db
so - there are no created_at and updated_at fields in your alerts table

your should create migration for adding that fields

```
class AddTimestampsToAlerts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:alerts) do |t| 
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you reloaded the console, either via reload! or restarting it?

Comment: Thanks, Ho Man. Yes. I have.